# Using UIImageView's layer.border property to set the border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView which has an image. The `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` looks like this:

```
#define BORDER_WIDTH_SELECTION 3
#define SELECTED_SCALE_VALUE 1.3

    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    smallFrame_ = frame;
    float newX = self.center.x - ((self.frame.size.width*SELECTED_SCALE_VALUE)*0.5);
    float newY = self.center.y - ((self.frame.size.height*SELECTED_SCALE_VALUE)*0.5);
    bigFrame_ = CGRectMake(newX, newY, self.frame.size.width*SELECTED_SCALE_VALUE, self.frame.size.height*SELECTED_SCALE_VALUE);
    self.layer.borderWidth = BORDER_WIDTH_SELECTION;
```

then later I trigger this

```
- (void) setSelected {
    [self makeThumbnailBig];
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0/255.0 green:19.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)makeThumbnailBig
{    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.frame = bigFrame_;
    }];
}
```

The `ImageView` scales correctly and draws a red border, but then the `image` within the `ImageView` **peaks out from underneath the border on the left by about a pixel or two**. I have removed the image, but this should give you an idea of the issue:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed it was `self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`. Mysterious user who deleted their answer, please return so I may accept!

Comment: there are more issues in your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code there is a line

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

According to the question it should be `YES` instead

About extra pixels:

When you are preparing the image size by division you could face the issue of magic image high resolution optimization. It starts by adding the fractal part to the UIImageView dimension. See [Points Versus Pixels](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)